# How to access methods of wrapper Highcharts vue?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vue-cli

im new to vue and highcharts.
I am using higcharts vue (vue CLI) imported in main.js this way:

```
import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";
Vue.use(HighchartsVue);
```

I call the chart component in my template in this way:

```
<highcharts
  v-if="isLoaded"
  :options="chartOptions2"
  :callback="myCallback"
></highcharts>
```

It works fine but I also need to access methods of this highcharts component.
I would like to do something like this:

`this.highcharts.reload(), this.highcharts.destroy()  or this.highcharts.rebuild()`

I searched web but I just found examples using CDN (not CLI projects).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We can use highcharts methods by referring to the chart instance. In the docs, it's well explained: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-object-reference

And here you've got example demos of using redraw and update method on the chart:
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-z3nrz
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-kdogc